# how to strip all child tags in an xml tag but leaving the text to merge to the parens using lxml in python?

Tags: python, tags, lxml, strip

How can one tell `etree.strip_tags()` to strip all possible tags from a given tag element?

Do I have to map them myself, like:

```
STRIP_TAGS = [ALL TAGS...] # Is there a built in list or dictionary in lxml
                           # that gives you all tags?
etree.strip_tags(tag, *STRIP_TAGS)
```

Perhaps a more elegant approach I don't know of?

Example input:

```
parent_tag = "<parent>This is some <i>text</i> with multiple <some_tag>tags</some_tag> and sometimes they <tt>are<bold> nested</bold></tt>.</parent>"
```

Desired Output:

```
# <parent>This is some text with multiple tags and sometimes they are nested.</parent>
```

or even better:

```
This is some text with multiple tags and sometimes they are nested.
```

Comment: Can you add example input and desired output?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`lxml.html.clean`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html) module:

```
import lxml.html, lxml.html.clean


s = '<parent>This is some <i>text</i> with multiple <some_tag>tags</some_tag> and sometimes they <tt>are<bold> nested</bold></tt>.</parent>'

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(allow_tags=['parent'], remove_unknown_tags=False)
cleaned_tree = cleaner.clean_html(tree)

print lxml.etree.tostring(cleaned_tree)
# <parent>This is some text with multiple tags and sometimes they are nested.</parent>
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a bit late, but I guess a simpler solution than the one provided by the initial answer by [ars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2611/ars) might be handy for safekeeping's sake.

**Short Answer**

Use the `"*"` argument when you call `strip_tags()` to specify *all* tags to be stripped.

**Long Answer**

Given your XML string, we can create an [lxml Element](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html):

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> s = "<parent>This is some <i>text</i> with multiple <some_tag>tags</some_tag> and sometimes they <tt>are<bold> nested</bold></tt>.</parent>"
>>> parent_tag = lxml.etree.fromstring(s)
```

You can inspect that instance like so:

```
>>> parent_tag
<Element parent at 0x5f9b70>
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(parent_tag)
b'<parent>This is some <i>text</i> with multiple <some_tag>tags</some_tag> and sometimes they <tt>are<bold> nested</bold></tt>.</parent>'
```

To strip out all the tags except the `parent` tag itself, use the `etree.strip_tags()` function like you suggested, but with a  `"*"` argument:

```
>>> lxml.etree.strip_tags(parent_tag, "*")
```

Inspection shows that all child tags are gone:

```
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(parent_tag)
b'<parent>This is some text with multiple tags and sometimes they are nested.</parent>'
```

Which is your desired output. *Note that this will modify the lxml Element instance itself!* To make it even better (as you asked :-)) just grab the `text` property:

```
>>> parent_tag.text
'This is some text with multiple tags and sometimes they are nested.'
```